# Applying CSS class to Html.DisplayFor (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

Am new to MVC, am am trying to apply CSS styles to Html.DisplayFor helper inside my template file: Shared>>EditorTemplate>>Contacts.cshtml. Below is my code:

```
@model People.Contacts
<div>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name) <span class="myclass">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastName)</span></div>
```

and my css class outside this template looks like this:

```
.myclass{font:italic bold;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Html.DisplayFor` does not support passing HTML attributes, including class/style. At it's most basic it merely renders the value, without any HTML, and with editor/display templates, it just renders whatever's in the template.

First, if you have `EditorTemplates\Contacts.cshtml`, that will actually never be used by `DisplayFor`. For `DisplayFor` you need a separate template in `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates`. As its name implies `EditorTemplates` is used by `EditorFor`.

Either `DisplayFor` or `EditorFor` are basically the same as calling `Html.Partial`. There's just some additional logic to deal with a specific model property and look by default in `DisplayTemplates`/`EditorTemplates` for the view. That said, you can pass additional data to them the same as you would with a partial, via `ViewData`.

For example, if you were to call `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "myclass" })`, then nothing would happen by default, but you would have a value of `"myclass"` in `ViewData["class"]`. You could then use that to modify a part of your template. For example:

**Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Contacts.cshtml**

```
<span @(ViewData["class"] != null ? "class='" + ViewData["class"] + "'" : string.Empty)>
    @ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue
</span>
```

That checks to see if `ViewData["class"]` has a value, and if so, adds a class attribute with that value to the span.

Comment: `Html.DisplayFor` is currently not well designed (as well as `Html.EditorFor`). We do need sometimes apply the same attributes, css classes to all top levels elements rendered inside the display & editor template. Also almost the cases we have just 1 top level element rendered for each display & editor template. You can do that task in each specific display & editor template but sometimes we need to abstract the code, we do one thing in one place instead of repeating it on all templates.

Answer (score 4):

As a different solutions you can use `Html.DisplayFor` in `<Label>` tag

```
<label class="control-label"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(p => p.HeadLine)</label>
```